# Can't open google apps script. All buttons and menu are disabled

Tags: google-apps-script

today I'm having some trouble opening the script editor.
The interface opens but the whole app seems to be disabled. I have no field to type the code and the buttons and menu bar are gray.

Can someone help me on this issue?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switch you drive locale settings to English and it will work. This is a temporary workaround to use until they fix the bug. [see issue 4339](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=4339)